# How to escape all HTML in a block in Rails ERB view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, escaping, erb

Essentially I want something like the following:

```
<code class="snippet">
   <%= html_escape do %>
      <a href="#">My markup displayed to user</a>
   <% end %>
</code>
```

However the html_escape method does not accept a block. If this is not built into Rails API somewhere else, perhaps using some helper, does anyone have advice on how to make a custom helper where the yield statement output is captured into a string that I can then escape myself?

Thanks,

Keith

Comment: I am realizing that maybe I should be marking up individual lines of HTML code escaped as strings to achieve the proper spacing.  Really I want something like the code snippet in this post minus the coloration and code formatting.

Comment: Do you want `<a href="#">My markup displayed to user</a>` to be displayed on the page?

Comment: Yes, and since I want the escaped HTML to be formatted in a particular way, I decided to compose the HTML manually as strings (very tedious) in a helper so I can add the proper line breaks and tabs.

Comment: I was never able to capture the ERB block and redisplay it as escaped HTML...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails' `capture` and `escape_once` helper methods can create a `String` from a block in an `erb` template and then output an escaped version of it:

```
<% snippet = capture do %>
    <a href="#">My markup displayed to user</a>
<% end %>
<code><%= escape_once snippet %></code>
```

`content_for` is another helper that provides similar functionality to `capture`, that you may consider using depending on the situation.

To explain, `snippet` is an `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, and is why `escape_once` is needed. You could achieve the same by calling `snippet.to_str` instead of `escape_once snippet` (However `.to_s` will not work as that is different to `.to_str` in `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`).

Comment: thanks for the answer. That is a great solution. I recently discovered capture and have been using it elsewhere.